# Lubuntu 22.04 Firefox upload window not showing and download issues

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, 22.04

I've updated **firefox** to the latest snap.

`latest/stable:    101.0.1-1    2022-06-09 (1443) 170MB`

When I try to upload a file to a website, it simply does not react: I click the website button, and nothing happens instead of showing the file selection window. It is a behavior happening on any website. Moreover, on websites offering the "drop the file here" area, I can smoothly drag-n-drop the file and make the upload. It is when there is the Upload button that it does not work. I have also tried the websites with chromium, and they perform regularly.

As the last step, I have also tried to start it in safe mode and even to refresh the installation (firefox --safe-mode -> refresh), but, alas, with no luck.

EDIT: It appears that downloads are also not working correctly.
When dealing with PDF files, for example, if the default action is "Open in Firefox", then after the PDF is shown, nothing happens if I click on the small icon for downloading the file. If the default action is "Always ask", when I click on the link of the PDF file, the selection window appear and, if there I choose "Open in Firefox", the small icon for downloading the files triggers the download.

Any hints?

Comment: Did you try removing it and reinstalling it? Do you have any errors while installing it? It could be also a bug of firefox since this version is very new though...

Comment: Where was the file located that you are trying to *drag/drop*?   Was it a location the *snap* package of `firefox` can access? as if it wasn't you may get what you're describing.   FYI:  I'm not using *jammy* (22.04), but just uploaded a picture to answer here (*I cancelled of course*) using `firefox` ver. 101.0.1-1 without issue on my Lubuntu *kinetic* box.

Comment: It was in a local folder of my laptop. The issue is that the file selection window does not appear, but I can upload a file with the drag/drop feature.

Comment: The *local* directory is what matters; as *snap* packages run *confined* meaning not all *local* files on your system are seen by a *snap* package such as `firefox` as they don't have access to your real file-system, seeing only part of it.   You can only *drag and drop* from files that *snap* packages can access themselves, ie. parts of the file-system directories they can see via dialog windows; but you weren't specific as to location (*where the file is located; local & network files are not what defines the rules - directories do*)

Comment: I see your point, but chromium also is a snap package like firefox, and chromium is able to show the file selection window when I click on the button on the website. Firefox simply does not react in any way when I click on the same button.

Comment: Have you used a `snap connect` type of command to give the `chromium` snap permission to access those folders? but not done the same for `firefox` ?  Without specifics we're somewhat limited to helping you.

Comment: Not really: I've not done anything special with chromium! However, I'm discovering many other oddities with firefox. Namely, downloads are also not working correctly.
For example, if the default action for PDF is "Opening in firefox", then after the pdf is shown, nothing happens if I click on the small icon for downloading the file. If the default action is "Always ask", and I choose "Open in Firefox", then the small icon for downloading the files triggers the download.
I'm modifying the question by adding these additional details.

Comment: You could try [this](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04).
snap has its own problems too... when it doesn't have full disk access, it can cause problems like this.

Comment: Now looking back at it it's probably a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem was related to the lacking in my system of the two packages `xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk`. I've noticed it starting firefox from command line and noticing this warning

`Can't open portal file chooser:DBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop was not provided by any .service files`

After installing via `apt` the two packages, everything started working again. I've erroneously removed them when purging all the fonts that were clogging my font-selection bar.